# Flutter - How to create widget that display RenderBox component?

Tags: dart, flutter

RenderBox gives the opportunity to overide paint() method. But how to build() Widget from that RenderBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` you can subclass `SingleChildRenderObjectWidget` (or similar)

```
class MyWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  @override
  MyRenderBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyRenderBox(title: "bar");
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, MyRenderBox renderObject) {
    renderObject.title = "foo";
  }
}

class MyRenderBox extends RenderBox {
  String title;

  MyRenderBox({this.title});
}
```

A few other interesting subclasses are `LeafRenderObjectWidget` and `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`

Comment: Still doesn't work... 
I/flutter (  601): This RenderObject has no descendants.
I/flutter (  601): ══════════
I/flutter (  601): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: MyRenderBox#ec2de relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT

Comment: It did work. But then you need to implement something inside `MyRenderBox`. That's out of the scope of this question though

Comment: I tried SingleChildRenderObject and LeafRenderObject.